# Getting Count of Cosmos DB Collection through REST API

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to get the number of records in a cosmos db collection through the REST api(we use it for our automation framework). The below approaches were tried.

Getting direct count – the count keyword wont work through the rest api of cosmos db

Getting the count of the incoming response – I fetched the results of ‘Select c.id from c’ and tried to get the count of the returned collection. However the maximum records returned were only 1000 which is the default. So I tried giving the x-ms-max-item-count in the header as a large value(40m) but still could get only 8k records even though the db record count was 28 million.

As a follow up to the above approach, there is a response header called ‘x-ms-continuation’  which according to the documentation can be passed in the subsequent requests if there are more records to be shown..for eg if we send the request first and the response had a non empty ‘x-ms-continuation’   then we can pass it in the second request to get the second page of results and get its size…and repeat the process so on till ‘x-ms-continuation’  is returned as null in the last response. However even this approach failed as I was getting a null response in the 4th or 5th cycle itself( the total count had not even reached 1 pc of the total).

Can anyone suggest an alternative method to get the count?

Comment: so this doesn't work? - {  
  "query": "SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c",  
  "parameters": [  ]  
}

Comment: no as count keyword is an aggregate function

Comment: Hi @david-makogon do you have any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get it through the REST API, you will be getting an error as it's an aggregate query

**""Cross partition query with aggregate functions is not supported."**

However if you pass the partition key header **"x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey"** you would be getting the result , but that's not a feasible solution.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to use that header - what value should i give? Also why isnt it a feasible solution

Comment: just set the partition key value for that header ,  for example if "zipcode" is the partition key it will give the count of all values for that particular partition key value. Then you need to iterate for all the possible values